# How to pass value to html input field which is opened through window.open()

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a function which has to values.Then at the end of the function Im doing window.open('/home.html').In that home.html I have 2 input fields for those I need to set values which I have in my fuction..
In my function Im trying to do by

```
function account(){
var a = "john";
document.getElementById('name').value = a;
window.open('/home.html','_blank');
}
```

But I dont get that value passed in my html when it opens since  it cant find that..How can we do this so once that html opens,this value a gets displayed in the field..Any help

Comment: try something like this `window.open('/home.html?id=1&name=2','_blank');`

Comment: @NaveenDA by adding ?id=1&name=2 ,html opened but my input field value didnt got added

Comment: make sure `home.html` is exits

Comment: yes it is present..It is redirecting me to that page